# update Trigger not working

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `ir_db1407`.`after_update_ind_user` AFTER UPDATE
ON `ir_db1407`.`ind_user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @user_id=OLD.id
IF (NEW.STATUS = '2' OR NEW.STATUS ='3') 
THEN 
 DELETE FROM ind_user_events WHERE user_id = @user_id;
 DELETE FROM ind_user_mobile WHERE user_id = @user_id;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Error Code : 1064
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL          server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (new.status = '2' or new.status ='3') 
 then 
 delete from ind_user_events wh' at line 7

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
SET @user_id=OLD.id
```

to

```
SET @user_id=OLD.id;
                   ^
```

You actually don't even need this variable. So ditch that line and try

```
...
IF (NEW.STATUS = '2' OR NEW.STATUS ='3') THEN 
  DELETE FROM ind_user_events WHERE user_id = OLD.id;
  DELETE FROM ind_user_mobile WHERE user_id = OLD.id;
END IF;
...
```